# Is there a way to improve this SparkSQL query logic to improve performance?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to make a select between 2 tables which I cannot join directly ( they don't have the same values ).

My 2 input table look something like this:

`Table1`:

```
Col4      |   Col3  |   Col2     |  Col1
ZO123     |   ZH10  |  Spark111  | 000567
VS561     |   JK14  |  Dmi563    | 009123
```

`Table2` ( here is the main problem, as we have concatenated values inside the cells):

```
    Col7         |     Col6      |    Col5    |  Col8
000567,009123    |   567,9123    |  ZH10,JK14 | Spark111
00657,00896      |   657,896     |  PK15,NU85 | Dmi563
```

`Table1` is a temp view as well with 410 million rows. `Table2` is a temp view with 221 rows.
Both are temp views built on top of some parquet files.

The query that I currently test and it's taking like 2 hours is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW Table3 AS SELECT w.Col1 AS Col1
w.Col2 AS Col2
w.Col3 AS Col3
w.Col4 AS Col4
m.Col5 AS Col5, 
m.Col6 AS Col6, 
m.Col7 AS Col7
m.Col8 AS Col8 FROM Table1 w,Table2 m
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE exists(split(Table2.Col5, ','), x -> x = w.Col3) AND Table2.Col5 = m.Col5 AND exists(split(Table2.Col6, ','), x -> x = udf_function_to_remove_zeros(w.Col1)) and Table2.Col6 = m.Col6 AND exists(split(Table2.Col8, ','), x -> x = w.Col2) AND Table2.Col8 = m.Col8)
```

The main idea is that I'm trying to retrieve rows from `Table1` where the values from rows can be found in the splited values from `Table2`. Also, all the conditions should be passed with AND.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing performance issues probably because you're:

- unnecessarily doing a cartesian product `FROM Table1 w,Table2 m`
- using UDF to remove leading zeros while you can do the same using builtin functions

You can actually write the same query using inner join like this:

```sql
SELECT
  w.Col1 AS Col1,
  w.Col2 AS Col2,
  w.Col3 AS Col3,
  w.Col4 AS Col4,
  m.Col5 AS Col5,
  m.Col6 AS Col6,
  m.Col7 AS Col7,
  m.Col8 AS Col8
FROM
  Table1 w
JOIN (
  SELECT
    Col7,
    Col8,
    INLINE(ARRAYS_ZIP(SPLIT(Col6, ','), SPLIT(Col5, ','))) AS (Col6, Col5)
  FROM
    Table2 
) m
ON
  w.Col3 = m.Col5
  AND TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM w.Col1) = m.Col6
  AND w.Col2 = m.Col8
```

Applied to your input example:

```py
spark.createDataFrame([
    ("ZO123", "ZH10", "Spark111", "000567"), ("VS561", "JK14", "Dmi563", "009123")
], ["Col4", "Col3", "Col2", "Col1"]).createOrReplaceTempView("Table1")

spark.createDataFrame([
    ("000567,009123", "567,9123", "ZH10,JK14", "Spark111"), ("00657,00896", "657,896", "PK15,NU85", "Dmi563")
], ["Col7", "Col6", "Col5", "Col8"]).createOrReplaceTempView("Table2")

spark.sql(above_query).show()

#+------+--------+----+-----+----+----+-------------+--------+
#|  Col1|    Col2|Col3| Col4|Col5|Col6|         Col7|    Col8|
#+------+--------+----+-----+----+----+-------------+--------+
#|000567|Spark111|ZH10|ZO123|ZH10| 567|000567,009123|Spark111|
#+------+--------+----+-----+----+----+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, thank you for your answer. Forgot to mention something from the beginning, in some case, for Table2 I can have 2 concatenated values in Col5 and just one single value in Col6. In this case, based on your solution, Col6 is splitted and now there are 2 rows, but on the second row Col5 has the value 'null'. That makes the JOIN have inaccurate results..

Comment: Tried solving this with a CASE WHEN inside the ARRAYS_ZIP but it doesn't work..

Comment: @PyRar what if `Col6` contains  `Col1` but `Col5` contains `Col3` in another row not the same ? do you consider it as it exists in table2? or does it have to be in the same row?

Comment: it has to be in the same row, exactly

Comment: @PyRar So the above code will work fine even if you have rows with `col6` having a single value. The conditions `w.Col3 = m.Col5 AND TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM w.Col1) = m.Col6` will filter the null values produced in `Col6` so it will not be included in the join result. Can you give an example of inaccurate result?